# Inter fragment communication after fragment creation

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my Acitivty i keep on switching between the fragements depending upon the user data.

Now lets say i have two Fragments A & B.

Now i want fragment A to communicate with B.

Upon some condition fragment might call the hosted activity to replace the current fragment with fragment B (with the commit operation which is scheduled as a work ).

Now i want some communication to happen from frag A to frag B (call a method on frag b from frag A)
But that method of frag B requires the whole creation process of frag B to happen which i don't know when will happen because that is happening asynchronously.

How can i achieve such scenario where frag A should help to crate frag B and then invoke a method on frag B.

I have checked the inter fragment communication topic http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html but that is more on how to replace a fragment. There is no info on how after that communication can happen.

cheers,
Saurav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could always go to your Activity `getActivity()`, ask if there is a Fragment you want to communicate with `findFragmentByXyz()` and do your stuff with it (or create it, if it's not created yet).

If you want to make sure, that you communicate with the other Fragment, when it's ready (e.g. when its UI is ready), you can post a 'Runnable' on the UI of Fragment B and notify your Activity/Fragment A/whatever, when you're ready.

```
getView().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (getActivity() != null) { // or whatever
             registerComponents();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: but one more comment is that this solution is pretty slow because i am waiting for the UI to get ready and the code executes asynchronously...is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Well I don't know how time-critical your requirements are, but it shouldn't be "slow" for normal use, because waiting for UI to load is not that long. Do you have to setup a complex UI, so it performs "slow"? Or why do you think so? By posting a Runnable to your View, you're just posting a new Message into the internal UI Thread Message Queue. So your Runnable will be executed after all others are finished. I.e. you know for sure that the UI is ready and you can update it.

Comment: If you need to do heavy work and don't want to wait for the UI and you want to notify the user, show a progress bar and start doing work inside `onCreate()` of your Fragment B. When it's finished, post a Runnable or use a Handler or use AsyncTask to update your UI.

Comment: yes progress bar is a solution...thanks a lot for your help @einschnaehkeee

Answer (score 1):

A possible way might be to make both of the fragments implement a common interface (let's call it `Subscriber`).
The interface shall look like this:

```
public interface Subscriber {
    void callMe();//to be used by the fragment who gets called
    void theOtherFragmentIsReady(Subscriber sub);//to be used by the fragment that will perform the call.
}
```

In the activity hosting the fragments add the following method:

```
public void fragmentCreated(Subscriber sub) {
     Subscriber fragmentA = ...;//retrieve fragment A
     fragmentA.theOtherFragmentIsReady(sub);//let the fragmentA that fragment B has been created
 }
```

Finally, in the onCreated() method of the fragments add:

```
 public void onCreate() {
     ((YourActivity)getActivity()).fragmentCreated(this);
 }
```