# Getting Null pointer Exception when trying to populate listview from fragment C to fragment B

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I am newbie to android development. I need to populate ListView in fragment B from the value selected by user in the spinner from fragment C.

So far what I tried is bundle method but its throwing null pointer exception.

Really I am  confused why this happen.

This is my code :

[How to pass spinner value from one fragment to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33673001/how-to-pass-spinner-value-from-one-fragment-to-another?noredirect=1#comment55120435_33673001).

I would be very glad if someone helps me **what is the procedure to communicate between fragments of same activity** .

This is my from_fragment(fragment c)

```
package com.example.first.servicefirst;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class NewRequirements extends Fragment {

//public static NewRequirements newInstance(Bundle bundle) {

//     Add myFragment = new Add();
//    myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
//}
    FragmentMigration framgnetmigration;
// }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_claim, container,
            false);
    Button btnupdate;
    btnupdate=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.update);
    final Spinner sbu=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.sbuu);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>adaptersbu=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            getActivity().getBaseContext(),R.array.newrequirements,  R.layout.spinnerlayout);
    adaptersbu.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sbu.setAdapter(adaptersbu);
    final Spinner bu=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.bu);

    adapterbu.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    bu.setAdapter(adapterbu);
    final Spinner sbuu=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.sbu);

    adaptersbuu.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sbuu.setAdapter(adaptersbuu);
    final Spinner sc=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.sc);
    ;
    adaptersc.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sc.setAdapter(adaptersc);
    final Spinner ssc=(Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.ssc);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>adapterssc=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
            (    getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.newrequirements, R.layout.spinnerlayout);
    adapterssc.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ssc.setAdapter(adapterssc);
    final String str=sbu.getSelectedItem().toString();

    btnupdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
                    Add add = new Add();

                    bundle.putString("yes", str);
                //    Log.i("Bundle", bundle.toString());
                    Log.v("Add", str);
                    add.setArguments(bundle);
                    FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, add,"hi");
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft.commit();

         }
    });
    return view;
 }





}


}
```

This is my to_fragment(Fragment B):

```
package com.example.first.servicefirst;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public  class Add extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
{
public static Add()
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_btn_add, container, false);
    Spinner ldsource=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lead_source);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.dropbox1, R.layout.spinnerlayout);


    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ldsource.setAdapter(adapter);
 //   EditText editText=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.title);

    Spinner ldtype=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ldtype);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.dropbox2,R.layout.spinnerlayout);

    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    ldtype.setAdapter(adapter1);
    Spinner ldstatus=(Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ldstatus);
    TextView txt=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTarget);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.dropbox3, R.layout.spinnerlayout);

    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item);
    ldstatus.setAdapter(adapter2);
  //  Bundle bundle=getArguments();
  //  String good=bundle.getString("sbu");
    ArrayList<LdNewsItem> listContact = GetlistContact();
    final   ListView lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ldrequirements);
    lv.setAdapter(new customListAdapterldrequirements(getActivity(), listContact));
//    lv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  //      @Override
    //    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //        return false;
       // }

        // Setting on Touch Listener for handling the touch inside ScrollView


    //});
     return rootView;


}




private ArrayList<LdNewsItem> GetlistContact()
{

    ArrayList<LdNewsItem> contactlist = new ArrayList<>();
    LdNewsItem contact = new LdNewsItem();
    String yog=getArguments().getString("yes");

    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
       // contact = new LdNewsItem( );
        contact.setSbu(""+yog);
       // contact.setBu(""+str);
       // contact.setSbuu("Yogeswaran" + str);
        contact.setSc("Sales" + i);
        contact.setSsc("term" + i);
        contact.setReq("business"+i);
        contactlist.add(contact);
    }

    return contactlist;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Fragment fragment=null;

    Button btnrequirements=(Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnrequirements);
    btnrequirements.setOnClickListener(this);

}
@Override

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnrequirements:
            Fragment newFragment = new NewRequirements();
            // consider using Java coding conventions (upper first char class names!!!)
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity()
                    .getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();

    }
}



}
```

Comment: Post the code where you are getting the null pointer exception

Comment: String yog=getArguments().getsString("sbu"); check my edit

Comment: YOu are passing "yog" ,Try  yog=getArguments().getString("yog ");

Comment: Still throws npe at same line

Comment: Is the god object null?

Comment: noo it is from spinners selected by users in fragment c

Comment: It seems that 'getArguments()' method is returning null. The fragment that you are instantiating in the 'onClick()' method of 'btnupdate' button's 'OnClickListener' is not the one getting displayed. Another instance of the same fragment 'Add' without a bundle is at play here.

Comment: Post the full code of fragment c.

Comment: package and import statements of fragment c are missing. Include them in the code.

Comment: everything is added i didnt paste it properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95314/discussion-between-vaishak-nair-and-m-yogeshwaran).

Comment: Where are you setting bundle data??

Comment: String yog=getArguments().getString("yes");

Comment: got struck with this issue

Answer (score 0):

The reference String that you are passing while putting the argument `args.putString("yog",god);`should be the same while you are retriving it `yog=getArguments().getString("yog");`

Comment: still getting same npe at same line